# How To Write The " Mark between two of Them

Tags: java, android, text

as we know we put The String (on The java) between " " So How can I write The " mark between  them on the java ? I need To appear Them on my programme but I can't do it because when I try to write The " mark between two " mark The Programme say That's Error ??

Comment: escape it with \, like \"

Answer (score 3):

Use backslash to escape the `"`:

```
String hello = "Hello, \"World\""; // Hello, "World"
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is your question... use  ("\"") this to get a string with a (") \ is the escape char to tell java that the next thing isn't code but a char while in a string.